# Prove this hierarchy conditional expectation equality

Tags: probability, bayesian

I am quite confused by this equation. Let $P_{x|\xi}$ denote the conditional distribution of $x$ with respect to $\xi$. Similarly, $\pi_{\theta|\xi}$ denote the conditional distribution of $\theta$ with respect to $\xi$. Then

\begin{align*}
P_{x|\xi}(A) = \int_{\Theta}P_{x|\theta}(A)d\Pi_{\theta|\xi}
\end{align*}

I understand the proof of $P_x(A)=\int_\theta P_{x|\theta}(A)d\Pi_{\theta}$. However, I am not sure this is true.

If I write $X,\Theta, \xi$ as random variable from sample space $\Omega$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then
\begin{align*}
P_{x|\xi}(A) = E[1_{X\in A}|\xi], \quad \int_{\Theta}P_{x|\theta}(A)d\Pi_{\theta|\xi} = E[P_{x|\theta}(A)|\xi] = E[E[1_{X\in A}|\Theta]|\xi]
\end{align*}
So this is literally saying
\begin{align*}
E[1_{x\in A}|\xi] = E[E[1_{X\in A}|\Theta]|\xi]
\end{align*}
However, this is true provided $\sigma(\xi)\subseteq \sigma(\Theta)$. But this is not necessarily true. i.e. This equation seems to not hold in general.

Is there any comments

Thanks in advance!